# Is package available on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I want to find out whether a package that is not installed on Ubuntu is available in my configured repositories using a shell script, preferably not one that needs to examine the output from a command to determine what is happening. I have no problems determining whether a package has been installed, but determining if it is available is another problem.

Comment: @guiverc OP asking if a package is available in the repositories, not if it is installed.

Comment: @guiverc, I am specifically asking whether a package exists in a remote repository that is in my sources list but not in the local copies of the repositories that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Change `redis` to whatever package you want to check.

```
grep "^Package: redis" /var/lib/apt/lists/*_binary-$(dpkg --print-architecture)_Packages
```

In my machine this yield.

```
$ grep "^Package: redis" /var/lib/apt/lists/*_binary-$(dpkg --print-architecture)_Packages
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-sentinel
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-server
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-security_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-tools
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-redisearch
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-redisearch-doc
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-sentinel
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-server
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-tools
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-sentinel
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-server
/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_bionic-updates_universe_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-tools
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_chris-lea_redis-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_chris-lea_redis-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-sentinel
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_chris-lea_redis-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-server
/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_chris-lea_redis-server_ubuntu_dists_bionic_main_binary-amd64_Packages:Package: redis-tools
```

You can see it output the one from Ubuntu main repository (`universe`), and external repository `chris-lea/redis-server`.

You can easily adjust this to your need, assuming you would create a shell script.

<sub>Steps taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/252333/list-all-packages-from-a-repository-in-ubuntu-debian.</sub>

Comment: I am interested in situations where the package is not present on the local system but only in the remote repository.

Comment: @Jonathan The command exactly did that, I don't have redis in my system. Could you elaborate what you mean ?

Comment: the documentation that I have read seem to imply that these commands only operate on the local copies of repositories or on the cache. Hence my question.